# Access type of a generic in Java

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to create a generic `Identifier` class which I would be able to use as follows:

```
public class TestGenericIdentifier {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Identifier<Car> carId = new Identifier<>(Car.IdentifierType.LICENSE_PLATE, "123 XYZ");
        Identifier<Person> personId = new Identifier<>(Person.IdentifierType.SOCIAL_SECURITY, "123456");
        System.out.println(carId);
        System.out.println(personId);
    }
}
```

To get there, I started by creating an `Identifiable` interface:

```
public interface Identifiable<T extends Enum> {}
```

The idea being that a class that implements `Identifiable` needs to provide an enum `T` in its declaration which is the type of the first parameter of the `Identifier` constructor:

```
public class Identifier<E extends Identifiable<T>> { //does not compile
    public Identifier(T type, String value) {
        //some code
    }
}
```

Now the code above does not compile as I can only use `Identifiable` (no parameter `T`) on the first line. If it worked I would be able to write the following two classes:

```
public class Car implements Identifiable<Car.IdentifierType>{

    public enum IdentifierType {
        SERIAL_NUMBER,
        LICENSE_PLATE;
    }
}

public class Person implements Identifiable<Person.IdentifierType> {

    public enum IdentifierType {
        DATABASE_ID,
        SOCIAL_SECURITY;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do that using generics?

EDIT 
One way is to compromise conciseness and keep compile-time type checking by doing:

```
public class Identifier<T extends Enum> {

    public Identifier(T type, String value) {
    }
}
```

and the main function becomes:

```
Identifier<Car.IdentifierType> carId = new Identifier<>(Car.IdentifierType.LICENSE_PLATE, "123 XYZ");
Identifier<Person.IdentifierType> personId = new Identifier<>(Person.IdentifierType.SOCIAL_SECURITY, "123456");
```

Comment: I'm wondering why you need `Identifier` when you already have `Identifiable`.

Comment: Basically, an Identifiable is an object that gives you an enum of the types of identifiers. So a Car is identifiable by 2 different types of Identifier: SERIAL_NUMBER and LICENSE_PLATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this to compile by tweaking your code a bit but I'm not sure it's what you want.  The following seems to work for me.

```
Identifier<Car.IdentifierType, Car> carId =
    new Identifier<Car.IdentifierType, Car>(Car.IdentifierType.LICENSE_PLATE,
        "123 XYZ");

public static class Identifier<T extends Enum, E extends Identifiable<T>> {
    public Identifier(T type, String value) {
        // some code
    }
}
```

The question is why do you want to do this?  If you edit your question some more with the background, I can edit my answer to be more helpful.

Comment: Yes that would work, but I am trying to make the code less verbose. What I am trying to achieve is to be able in the Identifier class to detect that Car is of type Identifiable<Car.IdentifierType>, and use Car.IdentifierType as a generic type in a method.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure you can do that with generics.  You can do it with runtime `instanceof` checks in your code of course.  Remember that you can certainly have an `enum` implement an `interface` if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Identifier<E extends Identifiable<? extends Enum>> {
    public Identifier(Enum type, String value) {
        //some code
    }
}
```

Might be enough for what you want

Comment: That would work but there is no type checking and I can then write:
    Identifier<Car> carId = new Identifier<>(Person.IdentifierType.SOCIAL_SECURITY, "123456");

Comment: I know. But be careful, you need a balance between type strength enforcement and readability / usability. You can have really complex generics constructs, but it's not always worth it. For example, you can check at runtime that the type is an "allowed one" and throw a RuntimeException if not (IllegalArgumentException?) - I know it's not the same as failing at compile time, but that may be enough